# Windows 8 freezes/creashes when playing video

Tags: windows-8, video, crash, windows-8-x64

My computer crashes sometimes watching movies or playing flash videos on the internet browser (I use Chrome).

What happens is while watching a movie I'm starting to hear a buzz and screen disappears, or sometimes audio keeps on playing for several moments before screen disappears. Then I either continue hearing that noise until I restart, either the computer restarts by itself.

I tried looking at the event viewer but I didn't manage to track the actual problem down.
I just see warnings like:

- (12:07:39) The system has rebooted without cleanly shutting down first. This error could be caused if the system stopped responding, crashed, or lost power unexpectedly.
- (12:08:02) The previous system shutdown at 11:49:21 PM on ‎4/‎24/‎2013 was unexpected.
- (12:10:22) The NVIDIA Update Service Daemon service failed to start due to the following error: 
  The service did not start due to a logon failure.
- (12:10:22) The nvUpdatusService service was unable to log on as .\UpdatusUser with the currently configured password due to the following error: 
  The password for this account has expired.
  To ensure that the service is configured properly, use the Services snap-in in Microsoft Management Console (MMC).
- (12:08:09) Custom dynamic link libraries are being loaded for every application. The system administrator should review the list of libraries to ensure they are related to trusted applications. Please visit http://support.microsoft.com/kb/197571 for more information.
- (12:07:43) The driver \Driver\WudfRd failed to load for the device ROOT\WPD\0000.

The truth is that I'm not an event viewer expert, and I'm hoping one of you experts will guide me on tracking down the problem source and solve it.

I tried updating the graphic card drivers with the latest version but the issue still persists.

The real issue is that I'm unable to reproduce the issue as it occurs randomly.

Comment: What's the behaviour with other browsers?

Comment: @Karan as I said , I can't really reproduce the issue. I don't use other browsers but Chrome, but it's obviously not a browser issue, since the issue occurs while watching movies on Media-Player-Classic as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my scenario it was due to a bug in the new update to graphics driver. When I rolled back to the previous driver version the problem was gone.

Answer (score 1):

A failing graphics card could cause these symptoms. You can troubleshoot this possibility by temporarily swapping graphics cards if you have another one.

Answer (score 0):

Check power supply, is it the correct rating for the card?  Disable hardware acceleration in the meantime in programs such as VLC and M Player classic.